# GeoJSON point collections is not shown in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

There is a GeoJSON collection of points. I tried to display it:

```
const source = new VectorSource({
    format,
  });

  source.addFeatures(format.readFeatures(geojson));

  const cluster = new Cluster({
    distance,
    source,
  });

  const layer = new VectorLayer({
    source: cluster,
    zIndex,
    maxZoom,

    style: (feature) => {
      const inventory =
        this.classificatorService.getInventory(inventoryObjectType);
      const { objectdisplaysettings } = inventory;

      return this.styleFunction(
        feature,
        {
          scale,
          anchorXUnits,
          anchorYUnits,
          anchor,
          src,
        },
        objectdisplaysettings
      );
    },
  });
```

Where style function is:

```
  styleFunction(feature, props, objectdisplaysettings: any) {
    const { iconColor } = objectdisplaysettings;
    return new Style({
      image: new Circle({
        radius: 7,
        stroke: new Stroke({
          width: 1,
          color: 'black',
        }),
      }),
    });
  }
```

As result I don't have any points on the map and any errors. What is wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question and add sample of your GeoJSON data.

Comment: Please format the code. So that it can be read easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss `new Feature()`

to get displayed on map all object shape need to define from `new Feature()`